# How can I redirect my users to a specific label when they visit my blog?

Tags: android, redirect, mobile, blogger

I'm starting a new blog and I want to streamline things for mobile users. How can I detect mobile users and redirect them to an specific label on my blog?

I searched around in the settings of blogger and the only thing that caught my attention really was the option to edit the html. I really have no clue what to do there to be honest though if thats what I need to edit.

Comment: what does this have to do with android tag?

Comment: I'm trying to get my blog to detect android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Blogger code `data:blog.isMobileRequest` and javascript.

```xml
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage and data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
<script>
var $tag = "YOUR_TAG";
document.location = document.location.origin + "/search/label/" + $tag;
</script>
</b:if>
```

Edit HTML and put the code after `<head>` then save the template.

The code checks if the URL has parameter `m=1` then it redirects to the chosen tag, and it only redirect home page url to prevent multiple redirects.